# why isnt the selected dropdown value being passed to the symbol?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tradingview-api

I have a dropdown list of elements, and using tradingview charting widget to display the chart for the selected symbol/pair.

Here is the html code :

```
  <select onchange = "selectChanged(this.value)">
    <option value="USDJPY">USDJPY</option>
    <option value="USDCAD">USDCAD</option>
    <option value="USDCHF">USDCHF</option>
    <option value="CHFJPY">CHFJPY</option>
    <option value="AUDUSD">AUDUSD</option>
    <option value="CADCHF">CADCHF</option>
    <option value="EURNZD">EURNZD</option>
    <option value="AUDJPY">AUDJPY</option>
    <option value="AUDNZD">AUDNZD</option>
    <option value="NZDCAD">NZDCAD</option>
  </select>
 
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_6214e"></div> 
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright">
    <a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">
    <span class="blue-text">AAPL Chart</span></a> by TradingView
  </div>
    
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js">
</script>
    
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
    "width": 430,
    "height": 310,
    "symbol": function selectChanged(newvalue),
    "interval": "D",
    "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
    "theme": "light",
    "style": "1",
    "locale": "en",
    "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
    "enable_publishing": false,
    "allow_symbol_change": true,
    "container_id": "tradingview_6214e"
  });
  </script>
</div>
```

what I am trying to do is show the price chart for the symbol/pair that is selected from the dropdown list, but it isn't working , what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The script is totally wrong. First ceate a separate function `selectChanged()` which updates the value of your trading view chart. How to update the symbol? For that you need to check the api docs for the library that you are using

Comment: Suggest you also check errors thrown in browser dev tools console and include such errors in question(s)